# Populating React Dropdown Getting Error #31

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've got a bit of Javascript defined as:

```
populateOptions() {
    var statesMap = [{1: 10}, {2: 20}, {3: 30}];

    return statesMap.map((option, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={option}>{option}</option>
    ));
}
```

This is called from the `render()` function:

```
<div className="col-md-3">
<select name="borrowerState" className="form-control dropDownStyle" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.borrower.borrowerState}>
    {this.populateOptions()}
</select>
```

When the page attempts to load, I get this in the console:

> Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B1%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
>       at e.exports (invariant.js:42)

Comment: Object are not valid as a child, from what I see each option and key and value is an object. You get something like this {1:10} for each option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering options which is an `object` inside your select options which is incorrect.
You should modify your statesMap and render function as below.

```
populateOptions() {

        var statesMap = [{'id': 1, 'data': 10}, {'id': 2, 'data': 20}, {'id': 3, 'data': 30}];

        return statesMap.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.id} value={option.data}>{option.data}</option>
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

***On a side note***

Since JSON don't parse the values which have `key` as numeric, it always expects it to be string.

So your JSON still be valid if you change `key` to string value

**Example**

[image]

However, `keys` which are not numeric, JSON automatically parse them into string -

```
var statesMap = [{name: 10}, {name: 20}, {name: 30}];
```

Like this is going to be parsed automatically because the `key` is considered to be a string.

**Example**

[image]

I hope its clear.